# HP Fortify - How to re-scan a project using analysis results from a previous scan on a different machine

Tags: fortify

I have opened the .fpr file to open the project and run the scan.  When I select the file to see the issue. I receive this message:

[image]

If I click No to use my current src folder I receive this message:

[image]

I want to update the path to point to my project's src folder.  I click Update Path and browse to appropriate src folder and click OK.

[image]

Now, when I make changes and want to Scan the project again, I click the Scan button.  But it won't scan the code.  Instead I receive the following message:

[image]

There must be a way to use analysis results from a previous scan.  I've never seen this error before.  Does anybody know how to do this or how to fix my weird situation?

FYI:  It even says in the [documentation](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/HPEAWBGuide1710.1211336542/help) in Chapter 3: Scanning Source Code that

```
2. Click Scan.
Note: You can only re-scan a project on the same machine where the project was originally
scanned.
The Rescan Build ID dialog box opens.
```

But I don't get the Rescan Build ID dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to list out a few different points, so please forgive me if my response seems a little disorganized

1. It looks like you are trying to use Audit WorkBench (AWB) to scan your project. I do not believe that you will be able to re-run a scan from AWB, using an FPR that was generated on a different host. You WILL be able to use the information in FPR that you already have, but you will need to use some other options which I will list below.
2. While you can use AWB to scan your source code, I would recommend against it. Instead, I'd recommend using a script that can be generated by Scan Wizard, From here, I will refer to that script as your "scan script". On the host where you generate the scan script, as long as you do not move the scan script from the location that it was generated in, as long as you don't move the root of your project directory to different location, and that you do not move the FPR after having successfully run a scan using the scan script, then all future scans that you run with that script will automatically merge the old & new results together into one FPR. That new merged FPR will include all audits, comments, and other modifications you have applied to your old. Using a scan script will give you greater flexibility to control your scan and it will make it easier for you to run your scans in a repeatable manner.
3. Your other option is to simply use AWB (or a scan script) to run a new scan and produce a new FPR. From there when you open your new FPR in AWB, you can use the Merge tool. Just make you have your **new** FPR opened in AWB when you are performing a merge; **not** your old FPR.